# automatic sql update from HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sql

I have a table with an list of orders on a homepage that is filled with data from a SQL database.
In this table there is a column with a checkbox.
My employees should click this checkbox when the ordered part has been delivered.
Now this change should be automatically updated in the database.
Is there a possibility without a separate "Safe button"?

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_res))
        {
            echo('<tr>');
            echo('<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>');
             echo('<td>' . $row['size'] . '</td>');
             echo('<td>' . $row['hersteller'] . '</td>');
             echo('<td>' . $row['anzahl'] . '</td>');
             echo('<td>' . $row['art'] . '</td>');
             echo('<td>' . $row['lieferant'] . '</td>');
             echo('<td>' . $row['termin'] . '</td>');
             echo('<td>' . $row['preis'] . '</td>');
             $chkd=$row['rad_da']?'checked="checked"':''; // 0: false; 1: true
             echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='rad_da[]' value='{$row['rad_Da']}' $chkd></td>";
             $chkd=$row['reifen_da']?'checked="checked"':''; // 0: false; 1: true
             echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='reifen_da[]' value='{$row['reifen_Da']}' $chkd></td>";
             $chkd=$row['montiert']?'checked="checked"':''; // 0: false; 1: true
             echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='montiert[]' value='{$row['montiert']}' $chkd></td>";
        }
```

This is my code and I thought of an onclick function, but my skills are too bad.

Comment: You can do it with javascript, but you have to do your research first. The answer is too huge and not applicatble to your code. The javascript could listen the change and call a service trough ajax to update the database. Security should be a concern also. Since your question is not answerable because is too broad, I will vote to close it but you could read and search and come back with a question more specific if you have doubts or problems

Comment: Here is a possibility, and as already mentioned it is not easy for beginner level PHP or JavaScript coding. You can write a JS function for the checkbox _onclick_ event listener. First, after the click make the checkbox not clickable again (you dont want to allow multiple clicks). Next, the JS function can have logic to extract the required data - HTML element data and PHP variables. This data is to be sent to the database by an Ajax call (you can use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to call the PHP code that updates the database).